# opencv2 Canny+findContours not working on some images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

i am trying to create a program that will detect and remove borders in a picture, the goal is to detect the document in the picture and clean it...

heres my code:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import rect

image = cv2.imread('./test.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 9)
ret, gray = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 10, 250)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

#x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])
#cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),0)

# get approximate contour
for c in contours:
    p = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * p, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        target = approx
        break


cv2.drawContours(image, [target], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imwrite('./final.jpg', image)
```

The image teste.jpg is:
[image]

but right now...the only thing it can find is:

[image]

...and as requested, heres a image that works:

[image]

Comment: You should do `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` instead.

Comment: i did it...the result was the same.

Comment: That means that it doesn't find the other contours. Have you had a look at the thresholded image? When I tried your code with the `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`, I wasn't getting the contours. I will post a solution in a bit

Comment: Can you post an image where it works?

Comment: Rick, i add the image that works...thanks

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? I'm using 3.4.3 and your code doesn't work as you say for the second image. Can you also add your results for the image where it is working?

Comment: Hi @RickM. ...sorry the third image was wrong, i uploaded the right one just now....

Comment: my open cv version => cv2.__version__  = 4.0.0

Comment: Thanks, and your results? I am not getting the correct results in my version of OpenCV so I want to see what you are expecting.

Comment: @RickM. what you want me to send? the resulting outlined image? (when it works?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189548/discussion-between-costamatrix-and-rick-m).

Comment: Yes, exactly that. I am in the chat room. Ping me when you are here!

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the chat, I would suggest you to use [Feature Description and Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html) for this. In my experience, it is faster than contours and you should be able to get around the problems with change in lighting, perspectives etc.

Here is what I tried:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def locater(image, source, num=0):
    def resize(im, new_width):
        r = float(new_width) / im.shape[1]
        dim = (new_width, int(im.shape[0] * r))
        return cv2.resize(im, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    #width = 300
    #source = resize(source, new_width=width)
    #image = resize(image, new_width=width)

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LUV)
    image, u, v = cv2.split(hsv)

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(source, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LUV)
    source, u, v = cv2.split(hsv)

    MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()
    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(image, None)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(source, None)

    flann = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DescriptorMatcher_FLANNBASED)

    des1 = np.asarray(des1, dtype=np.float32)
    des2 = np.asarray(des2, dtype=np.float32)

    matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

    # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test
    good = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
            good.append(m)

    if len(good) >= MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
        src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

        M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
        matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

        h,w = image.shape
        pts = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, h-1], [w-1, h-1], [w-1, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, M)
        source_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(source, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        img2 = cv2.polylines(source_bgr, [np.int32(dst)], True, (0,0,255), 3, 
                             cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imwrite("out"+str(num)+".jpg", img2)
    else:
        print("Not enough matches." + str(len(good)))
        matchesMask = None

    draw_params = dict(matchColor=(0, 255, 0), # draw matches in green color
                       singlePointColor=None,
                       matchesMask=matchesMask, # draw only inliers
                       flags=2)
    img3 = cv2.drawMatches(image, kp1, source, kp2, good, None, **draw_params)
    cv2.imwrite("ORB"+str(num)+".jpg", img3)

image = cv2.imread('contour.jpg')
source = cv2.imread('contour_source.jpg')
locater(source, image, num=1)
```

Source image:

[image: Source]

Results:

[image: Result 1]

[image: Result 2]

**Some Notes**: As the *source* image wasn't so good, the homography is *just fine*. You can make it more accurate by getting a better quality of the image - by scanning the original with a decent scanner, resizing the image (I added a function for that) and by using a different color space (I use LUV here).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Rick.... it would be too much to ask how i crop and warp transform the red box into a final rectangle image ? 8-)

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/)

Comment: Hi Rick... thanks, but i was not able to understand the page....they use fixed coordinates, and i got confused....why the coordinates are fixed on the program??? pts_src = np.array([[141, 131], [480, 159], [493, 630],[64, 601]])

Comment: i just need now to get the box coordinate of this "red box" and crop the image...

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation at [docs.opencv.org](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de) , you will find that it has a number of parameters you can supply, like:

1. `threshold1`: first threshold for the hysteresis procedure.
2. `threshold2`: second threshold for the hysteresis procedure.
3. `apertureSize`: aperture size for the Sobel operator.
4. `L2gradient`: a flag, indicating whether a more accurate L2 norm should be used to calculate the image gradient magnitude ( `L2gradient=true` ), or whether the default L1 `norm =|dI/dx|+|dI/dy|` is enough ( `L2gradient=false` ).

I'd suggest playing with these to get the desired results.

Comment: Thanks vahdet, but i post this only after several hours of testing.....i played with this parameters, with no result....the final code for Canny is:                                                                                 v = np.median(gray)
sigma=0.33
#---- apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median----
lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))

edges = cv2.Canny(gray, lower, upper, apertureSize = 3)

Comment: i tried several things, even change the image to B&W and the do the findcontours, but nothing..... but with other images, it works fine.